# How can i call this method in self.view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, drawrect

I am making this method for drawing line now what I want is to call it in another methods how can I do that, please help me out of this that how can I add this in self.view?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

     CGFloat dashArray[] = {2,6,4,2};

     CGContextSetLineDash(context, 3, dashArray, 4);

     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10, 200);

     CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, 150, 10, 300, 200);

     CGContextStrokePath(context);

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

This will call your draw rect method.

Comment: It won't call the `drawRect` method at all; it will tell Cocoa Touch to call it sometime later.

Answer (score 8):

Mark the view as needing a redraw:

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay).

Comment: @HasnatTariq Then you haven't explained your problem properly.

Comment: i want to draw a dashed line rect on my self.view help me how can i make this

Comment: @HasnatTariq So is the `drawRect` method failing?  Is it being called when you expect (add logging)?  What is the view subclass?

Comment: actually when i was callin it in another method like this '[self drawRect:CGRectMake(10,10,200,200)];]' its not showin any kind ov rect in ma view..

Comment: @HasnatTariq You cannot call this method directly; you have to use `setNeedsDisplay` instead (see the `UIView` class reference for the `drawRect` method, which states this).

Comment: @HasnatTariq This DOES work. If your method is not invoked in response to setNeedsDisplay, then there is something wrong in your inheritance structure.